# Node OPC UA Monitored Item. How to get data after a given time

Tags: javascript, node.js, monitoring, opc-ua, node-opcua

I am using a node opc ua client to connect to a opc ua server. I have added a subscription for an item on the server like this:

```js
...

addMonitoringFor(opcNode, callback) {
  const monitoredItem = opcSession.monitor({
      nodeId: opcua.resolveNodeId(opcNode.nodeId),
      attributeId: opcua.AttributeIds.Value
    }, {
      samplingInterval: 100,
      discardOldest: true,
      queueSize: 10
    },
    opcua.read_service.TimestampsToReturn.Both
  );

  monitoredItem.on("changed", dataValue => {
    if (dataValue === undefined || dataValue.value === null) {
      callback(`The subscription for the Opc Servernode ${opcNode.nodeId.replace(/\./g, " ")} failed.`);
    } else {
      callback(null, dataValue.value.value);
    }
  });
}

...
```

The on change function is only called when the data actually changes but i would like to have the data for a concrete time series.

How can this be achieved?

Comment: I think the opc server decides that. You should configure it on server side